# karma/jasmine/angularJS : unit testing my own modal directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, karma-jasmine

in order to easily create a [modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal), i want a directive that simply takes a template and then creates a button that opens a modal with the template as the content.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate.html">
<h1>hello world</h1>
</script>
<div my-modal="myTemplate.html"></div>
```

Now, i create a new angularJS directive in my module that simply returns a template that has a `ng-click` that then opens the modal:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives').directive('myModal', ['$modal',
  function($modal) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.modalController = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
        };

        scope.openModal = function() {
          var modalInstance = $modal.open({
          templateUrl: attrs.myModal,
          controller: scope.modalController
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function () {}, function () {});

        return modalInstance;
      };
    },

    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      myModal: '='
    },
    transclude: false,
    template: '<button ng-click="openModal()">open</button>'
  };
}]);
```

This works in my app. You can see the [plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/BCSDTAy50jf0vco1CuVy?p=preview).

The Problem is that i can not get the test to work. It tried both the jasmine.clock and the $timeout approach but it still does not seem to work.

Here is my test:

```
(function () {
  "use strict";

  describe('my-modal', function() {
    var element,
        scope,
    apply,
    triggerClick,
    $timeout;

        beforeEach(module('myApp.services'));
        beforeEach(module('myApp.directives'));
        beforeEach(module('pascalprecht.translate'));
        beforeEach(module('ui.bootstrap'));

        describe('directive', function() {

          beforeEach(function(){
            jasmine.Clock.useMock();
          });

          beforeEach(inject(function($injector,$compile) {
            var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $timeout = $injector.get('$timeout');
            apply = function () {
              /* This is a workaround because. Read up on it here: http://tinyurl.com/ng8zzub */
            if(!scope.$$phase) {
              scope.$apply();
            }
          };

          triggerClick = function(element){
            $(element).trigger('click');
            apply();
          };

          var html =
            '<html><body>' +
              '<h1>PETER?</h1>' +
              '<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalTemplate.html">' +
               '<h1>Hallo Peter</h1>' +
                '<p>Was geht?</p>' +
              '</script>' +
              '<div my-modal="myModalTemplate.html"></div>'
            '</body></html>';

          element = $compile(html)(scope);
          scope.$digest();
        }));

        it('should open uppon click on directive element', function() {
          triggerClick($(element).find('button'));
          jasmine.Clock.tick(9000);
          $timeout.flush();
          apply();
          expect($(element).find('.modal').length > 0).toBeTruthy();
        });
      });
    });
  }());
```

Sadly, the test fails.

In the [unit-tests](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/test/modal.spec.js) that ui-bootstrap itself uses to prove that it's modal component is working, they directly check the $document which is not an option for me.

So one weird thing is, when i use `console.log()` to see if `element` has changed at all, i see that the `html` and `body` tag has been stripped. But modal uses the body to append elements to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the Problem was that ui-bootstrap.modal uses $document to append it's html, rather than using the directive that called it as a refference.

So to test weather or not the modal is called by the directive, we have to search for it in the $document. I injected that in my tests in beforeEach:

```
var $document;
beforeEach(inject(function(_$document_) {
  $document = _$document_;
}));
```

Then in my actual test i used it to find the modal elements like this:

```
it('should open uppon click on directive element', function() {
  expect($document.find('.modal-open').length > 0).toBeFalsy();
  expect($document.find('.modal').length > 0).toBeFalsy();
  triggerClick(element.find('button'));
  expect($document.find('.modal-open').length > 0).toBeTruthy();
  expect($document.find('.modal').length > 0).toBeTruthy();
}
```

It works!